# Displaying only last number of my score

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a button that sends my points to another Activity:

```
public void nextButton(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(quiz_activity.this, score_activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("some_key", points);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and in the other Activity I have:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int point = bundle.getInt("some_key");
```

When I want to display my score there I do it by

```
TextView scoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        scoreTextView.setText("" + point);
```

It works fine when the score is <= 10, but when it's higher only last number is displayed..
There is also my score `TextView`:

I'm sorry, here is my score_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vaš rezultat na ovom testu je:"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>


        </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="99"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="/40"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/score1"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/all_rights"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is quiz_layout, I'm making some kind like a quiz/test implemented in my app..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yourId"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1. HTTP je skraćenica za:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_HyperTextTransferProvider"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hyper Text Transfer Provider"
                android:onClick="fourthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_HyperTranslateTransferProtocol"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hyper Translate Transfer Protocol"
                android:onClick="fourthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_HyperTextTransferProtocol"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hyper Text Transfer Protocol"
                android:onClick="fourthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="fourthRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2. FTP je protokol koji omogućuje:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_morespeed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="veću brzinu download-a velikih datoteka"
                android:onClick="fifthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_transferdata"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="prenos datoteka među računarima na internetu"
                android:onClick="fifthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_controlcomputer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="kontrolu računara putem interneta "
                android:onClick="fifthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="fifthRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>




        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3. Program za crtanje koji dolazi u sklopu Windows operativnog sistema naziva se:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>


    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_paint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Paint"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_photoshop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Photoshop"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_coreldraw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CorelDraw"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ne znam"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
    </RadioGroup>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4. Kako se nazivaju programi koje korsitimo da bi zaštitili računar od virusa?"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_driveri"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Drajveri"
                android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_antivirusi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Antivirusi"
                android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_editori"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Editori"
                android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>



        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5. Skraćenica WWW označava:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_wordwindowweb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Word Window Web"
                android:onClick="thirdRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_worldwideweb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="World Wide Web"
                android:onClick="thirdRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_worldwidthweb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="World Width Web"
                android:onClick="thirdRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="thirdRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6. Prva računarska mreža se nazivala:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_arpanet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ARPANET"
                android:onClick="sixthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_lannet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LANNET"
                android:onClick="sixthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_adslnet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ADSLNET"
                android:onClick="sixthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="sixthRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7. AutoCAD je vrsta programa koja služi za:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_uredjivanje"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Uređivanje fotografija"
                android:onClick="seventhRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_crtanje"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Crtanje likovnih crteža"
                android:onClick="seventhRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_projektovanje"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tehničko projektovanje"
                android:onClick="seventhRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="seventhRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8. Mrežna struktura na slici je:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mrezna"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_razgranata"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Razgranata"
                android:onClick="eightRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_magistrala"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Magistrala"
                android:onClick="eightRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pravolinijska"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pravolinijska"
                android:onClick="eightRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="eightRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>




        <Button
            android:text="Potvrdi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:onClick="nextButton"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have my RadioButtons there and when someone click one of them they get +2 if they answer correctly  or -1 point if they don't. The problem is when someone answers most questions right, and when the score is 10+.. If I have 16 score, it will display 6 not 16.

Here are the screeshots from the app, I answer all questions right and my score is 16, but instead it displays 6
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOgRK.png) [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTb0E.png)

quiz_activity where I increment or decrement my points:

```
public class quiz_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
int points = 0;
Toolbar toolbar;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_layout);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }


    });


}

public void firstRadioButtons(View view) {

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {


        case R.id.radio_paint:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_photoshop:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_coreldraw:
            if (checked)
                --points;

            break;
    }



}
public void secondRadioButtons(View view) {

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_driveri:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_editori:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_antivirusi:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
            break;
    }

}
public void thirdRadioButtons(View view) {

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_wordwindowweb:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_worldwideweb:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_worldwidthweb:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
    }

}
public void fourthRadioButtons(View view) {

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_HyperTextTransferProvider:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_HyperTranslateTransferProtocol:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_HyperTextTransferProtocol:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
            break;
    }

}
public void fifthRadioButtons(View view) {

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_morespeed:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_transferdata:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_controlcomputer:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
    }

}
public void sixthRadioButtons(View view) {

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_arpanet:
            if (checked)
                points = +2;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_lannet:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_adslnet:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
    }

}
public void seventhRadioButtons(View view) {

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_uredjivanje:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_crtanje:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_projektovanje:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
            break;
    }

}
public void eightRadioButtons(View view) {

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_razgranata:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_magistrala:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_pravolinijska:
            if (checked)
                --points;
            break;
    }

}
public void nextButton(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(quiz_activity.this, score_activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("some_key", points);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Comment: add more details / screenshots

Comment: That sound like a layout problem. Can you show us the layout, where is textview is embedded?

Comment: Please post your full xml file.

Comment: Can you update your original post to include screenshots too? I tried your xml and it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/PjeNHjk), I added an extra int, but is that not what you are expecting?

Comment: I added what you asked for, take a look..

Answer (score 0):

Change the below `LinearLayout`'s `layout_width` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

Then in the same `LinearLayout`, add `android:gravity="center"`. This centers the `TextView`s that are in your `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:text="99"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="/40"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/score1"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it before and now again but it didn't worked.. :/ I tried to make space around the Textview bigger, but it didn't make any improvements.

Comment: Could you please update your original post with the code you use to calculate the score? Also, what happens if you statically set the text on the `android:id="@+id/score"` like you did above using `android:text="99"`, does it display 99 correctly?

Comment: OP updated.. It displays 99 correctly, when my score is 10 it displays 10, but when it's above there is a problem